# Plotting with X as date range

Tags: plot, gnuplot

My data is formatted like so:

```
2014-11-17 19 18
2014-11-18 8 20
2014-11-19 23 16
2014-11-20 28 20
```

and so on.

My gnuplot script is the following:

```
gnuplot -e "
    set output 'commits-per-day-with.png';
    set term png truecolor giant;
    set xdata time;
    set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d';
    set format x '%Y-%m-%d';
    set xrange ['$min_date':'$max_date'];
    set xtics 7;
    set grid y;
    set boxwidth 1.0 relative;
    set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder;
    plot '$tmp_file' using 0:2 with boxes title 'authored',
         '' using 0:3 with boxes title 'committed';
"
```

It's embedded into a shell script, as you can see. The `$min_date` and `$max_date` variables are formatted like so: `2014-01-01`, so just like the format in the data (it's actually retreived from the data) and the format specified.

`$tmp_file` is the file with the data, of course.

gnuplot tells me:

```
line 0: all points y value undefined!
```

What is my error?

Comment: Is there something wrong with your $tmp_file? It seems all right on my platform (gnuplot version 4.6 patch level 6 on Ubuntu 12.04) except that I use the default wxt terminal and not set the xrange. It does produce a graph. By the way, why do you plot with `using 0:2` instead of `using 1:2`?

Comment: I'm not a gnuplot specialist, I hacked this with a friend which has some experience with gnuplot, but doesn't know how to do this properly either...

Comment: But it shouldn't be too difficult to use `using 1:2` like @DragonHu suggested…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, as suggested by the comments, the column 0.

You tell gnuplot to plot timestamps on the xaxis. On a computer, timestamps are represented by a number, usually counting the seconds since a point in the past. This point is 1970-1-1 00:00:00 in most cases, however, in gnuplot, it's 2000-1-1.

Column 0 is a special column, counting the rows of the dataset currently drawn (i.e. line number in your case). So, the x-values of your data are 1, 2, 3, ...

So, your x-values are the first seconds of the year 2000, but you specify a range in 2014. No wonder  that there's nothing to plot.

As said, plot `using 1:` and gnuplot will parse the timestamp from your first column correctly.

Comment: If I do `using 1:2` instead of `0:2` it tells me `line 0: Can't plot with an empty x range!`.

Comment: Then you probably haven't defined `$min_date` and `$max_date` properly. If I use `using 1:2` for the first, `using 1:3` for the second plot, leave out `set xtics 7` (which is also wrong), and remove `set xrange ...` it works fine.